# Can we distribute connectives over quantifiers?

Tags: logic

I apoligise for lack of LaTex

Are these Equivalent statements?

$\forall x (Ix \to \exists y (Py \land Qxy))$

$\forall x \exists y (Ix \to (Py \land Qxy))$

I am essentially asking if we can distribute a disjunctive connective (material implication) over the Existential Quantifier (essentially a string of disjunctions).

Similarly, one might ask if a conjunction could be distributed over the Universal Quantifier?

Comment: I guess the point is that $Ix$ does not mention the variable $y$, so we can exchange "$Ix \rightarrow$" with the quantifier "$\exists y$".

Comment: This may help: Think of "and" as a binary for-all and "or" as a binary there-exists, and recall that order doesn't matter with multiple for-all's -- $(\forall \,x)(\forall \, y)$ can be replaced with $(\forall \,y)(\forall \, x)$; and recall that order doesn't matter with multiple there-exists -- $(\exists \,x)(\exists \, y)$ can be replaced with $(\exists \,y)(\exists \, x).$ However, $(\forall \,x)(\exists \, y)$ is NOT the same as $(\exists \,y)(\forall \, x).$

Comment: I added the mathjax code. Please look at how I did that so you can do this for any future posts yourself.

Comment: What you are doing is not so much Distribution, as it is moving a quantifier over an operator. For a bunch basic principles of both Distribution and moving quantifiers, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118012/quantifier-positioning   You will find your particular case as an instance of the fourth Prenex law for Conditionals I posted there.

Comment: If you're interested, I have some notes (logic formulations with English language examples) on these issues that I wrote and used as part of workshop I gave a couple of years ago for item writers of high stakes graduate level tests. If you're interested, [send me an email](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3118246/344246